# start and end location after piece movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a checker variation game. 
I am new  to jquery but through some help the pieces can now move around the board.

Is there a way to indicate the start location and end location of a move?

I would also like to disable all piece movement once a move has been made.

jsfiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/mwu3u/1/

Thanks.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function drag(ob){       
  ob.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ob.target.id);     
}

function drop(ob){
  var id = ob.dataTransfer.getData("Text");     
  var t = ob.target;    
  if (ob.target.nodeName == "IMG")
    t = ob.target.parentNode;
  t.innerHTML = "";
  var img = document.getElementById(id);
  t.appendChild(img);
  ob.preventDefault();    
}

function allowDrop(ob){
  ob.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: no time to develop a full answer but to stop the dragable, here's a technique I've used before: give your dragable divs a css class of say "dragableDiv" (the css itself can be empty, it's just a marker) and in your drop event handler, use a jquery css selector to set the dragabale attribute to false for any div with a css class of "dragableDiv"  For the other part, your target divs should be given an id similar to your td's and you can then dig out the target element's id in your drop handler. It's been a while so I can;t remember the syntax exactly and I have to run now.

Comment: I will try this path though I am not sure if it will work with dragging an image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easily if you agree to use JQuery (your code above doesn't contain JQuery source code)

Have a look on the JQueryUI draggable and droppable widget http://jqueryui.com/

Here is a piece of code permitting to retrieve the source location after element dropping :

```
  $( ".cases" ).droppable({ 
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(event.target.id);
        console.log(ui.draggable[0].parentElement.id);

        var target = event.target.id;
        var source = ui.draggable[0].parentElement.id;

    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know of any working examples using a table and an image? I have found a found a few that use text. I am not sure how to get started.